# Insert jquery array to db in CI

Tags: jquery, continuous-integration

I recently started working with CI and I am fairly new to JQuery. Still trying to get hold of it.

I am able to select multiple dates in a calendar as well as dis-select them. Also submit button is showing and hiding on date choose.

I have array of these dates which I not sure how to get converted to php (or get it to form submit). I don't know where to start from?

```js
 $('td').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active-select-color');
  if($('td').hasClass('active-select-color'))
   $('#mark-now').show();
  else
   $('#mark-now').hide();
 });
 var selected = [];
 var tbl = document.getElementById("calender-table");
 if (tbl != null) {
 for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
 tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
   var item = getval(this);
   if($(this).hasClass('active-select-color')){ 
   selected.push(item);
  } else {
   var index = selected.indexOf(item);
   selected.splice(index, 1);
   }
 console.log(selected);
   }
  }
 }
 function getval(cel) {
   return cel.innerHTML;
   <!-- alert(cel.innerHTML); -->
 }
```

```css
 table{
  border:3px solid #FD5196;
  margin-top:7px;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  empty-cells:hide;
 }
 td{
  color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid #E6C1EB;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:#fff;
 }
 .active-select-color{
  background-color:red;
 }
 
 td:empty{
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid #E6C1EB;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:#fff !important;
  pointer-events: none;
 }
 td:hover{
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  border:2px solid #E6C1EB;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
 th{
  background: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .prevcell a, .nextcell a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
 }
 
 tr.wk_nm{
  background:#E6C1EB;
  color:#AB08BD;
  font-size:17px;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:10px;
  padding:5px;
 }
 
 .highlight{
  background:#FD5196;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
 }
 .disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
 }
.div-inline {
 float:left;
 margin-top:7px;
 margin-left:2%;
 font-weignt:bold !important;
 padding:5px;
 width:40%;
}
.green-rect {
 height:25px;
 width:25px;
 background-color:#fff;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.red-rect {
 height:25px;
 width:25px;
 background-color:red;
}
.mark-booked {
 margin-top:10px;
 padding:7px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:blue;
 border-radius:5px;
 float:left;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:125%;
}
.submit-dates {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 15px 2px 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" id="calender-table">

<tr>
<th class="prevcell"><a href="http://localhost/admin/dashboard/manage-availability-calendar/2016/06">&lt;&lt;</a></th>
<th colspan="5">July&nbsp;2016</th>
<th class="nextcell"><a href="http://localhost/admin/dashboard/manage-availability-calendar/2016/08">&gt;&gt;</a></th>
</tr>

<tr class="wk_nm disabled">
<td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td><td>Sun</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td>
</tr>

</table>

<?= form_open('dashboard/insert-calender-dates'); ?>
<input id="mark-now" style="display:none;" type="submit" class="submit-dates" value="Mark as booked">
<?= form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: @Shubham Kahtri.. dont know how to use `selected.push(getval(this)` to save the selected values as array